# DBNull exception when passing null value in DB

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, devexpress

I have this piece of code and I am getting exception

> The value for column IsVisible in Features is 'DBNull'

for featureValue.IsVisible. I know that I need to verify to not be DbNull.Value or assing a Value if they are. But I don't know how to do this verifications in my context where I have code in Linq

```
ComboBoxEdit comboBox = new ComboBoxEdit();


var featureValues = 
        from featureValue in this.productsDataSet.FeatureValues
        where (featureValue.FeatureId == feature.FeatureId && featureValue.IsVisible == true) 
        select featureValue.Value;

comboBox.Properties.Items.AddRange(featureValues.ToArray());
comboBox.Properties.AutoComplete = true;
comboBox.Properties.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor;

return comboBox;
```

I tried :

```
 !IsDbNull(featureValue.IsVisible)
 !IsNull(featureValue.IsVisbile)
```

The name 'IsNull' does not exist in the current context

```
 featureValue.isVisbile == DBNull.Value
```

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'DBNull'

```
!featureValue.IsNull(featureValue.IsVisible)
```

Cannot convert from 'int' to 'bool'
I am getting errors for all

Comment: which errors....?

Comment: `featureValue.IsVisible == true` shouldn't give a null reference excption. Even if `IsVisible` is as you claim `DBNull` it would just be `false`, because `DBNull` isn`t actually `null` and will not cause a null reference exception. But it can't be `DBNull` entityframework, I am assuming you are using this, will not populate objects with DBnull but a simple null instead.

Comment: @Rand Random it is from here, I did debug and when I assigned values for IsVisible it did not occur anymore, but I need it to work even with null values

Comment: Modify this code to get a null reference exception: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yq5D5O - as you can see I did initialize `IsVisible` with `null` on line 12, but the code runs without an issue.

Comment: Since your error is something completly different, than what I thought. Have a look at this: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t681573/wpf-comboboxedit-and-dbnull-item-value

Comment: https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.LookUpEditBase.SelectItemWithNullValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following

```
var featureValues = 
    from featureValue in this.productsDataSet.FeatureValues
    where (featureValue.FeatureId == feature.FeatureId && featureValue.IsVisible.HasValue && featureValue.IsVisible == true) 
    select featureValue.Value;
```

Comment: I am getting:
Error CS1061 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue' and no accessible extension method 'HasValue' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found

Comment: You will need to make your bool variable nullable by declaring is as bool? instead of just bool

Comment: Yes, I did. For new variables it will assign false by default, but I need to work for the old ones, which are null